# Java - How to avoid periodic operation execution overlapping

Tags: java, android, java.util.concurrent

I've some periodic operation to be performed in my application, say of period `T`. For now, i'm using `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask, 0, T)`. Now I want to avoid the overlapping of the single operations (in some cases a single operation could take more time than `T`). I've read `Timer` implementation use a single thread to execute operations, so there would be no overlapping in a standard situations. The problem is that in my case the single operations are not executed directly by the `TimerTask` passed to `Timer`: operations are only started from it, and they are executed asynchronously.

So, there could be overlapping if a `TimerTask` execution starts a new operation before the previous has finished. Instead, if overlapping occurs, I want to wait the termination of previous execution and start a new operation as soon as previous completed.

What would be the best implementation to obtain this behavior? Should I switch from Timer to another support? It's Android environment, so I prefer a Java standard (`util.concurrent`) or some Android-based implementation instead of other based on Spring Quartz and other specific frameworks.

Comment: Why don't you schedule the next task at the end of the current one? This will solve all your problems, and will avoid battery drain if your task duration is just a little bit less than T

Comment: It could be a solution, but in this way I need to control explicitly the execution period, remembering the start timestamp, verifying how much time execution takes, and so on.. Isn't there a more elegant solution? PS: can you better explain how this specific solution will save battery if task duration is just a little bit less than T?

Comment: You are telling me that your task takes sometimes more than T secondes, because you fear to overlap. That means that if your task is T minus 1 seconde, your task will run every T with a duration of T-1s, and means that you have only 1 seconde where your battery is not used. Scheduling a second task after T seconds after the end of the first one will gives you a T secondes without draining the battery.. Or maybe I have misunderstood something?

Comment: No. T must be an exact period when an operation takes less than T. This means that if operation "n" starts at T0(n), next operation must start at T0(n)+T... It should be delayed only if operation n takes more than T. Then T(n+1)=max( T0(n)+T, Tf(n) ) where Tf is when operation n finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29) to achieve this. It's much easier to use than `Timer{,Task}`.

Comment: And what will ensure the single operations will not overlap? Even creating a single-threaded pool, as I wrote single operations are asynchronous and are not directly executed by the thread.

Comment: Well, that is what an `ExecutorService` does: it executes tasks asynchronously; and since you have only one thread, until the previous task is not finished, the second will not execute.

Comment: Even Timer and TimerTask executes asynchronously, since they execute in a separate thread. I wrote a different think. In my case the single operations are asynchronous, so the thread is not busy in the execution of the operation. It execute only to start the operation, that is completed in background. So multiple execution of the thread will start concurrent executions of the operation, and I want to avoid this.

Comment: Read again what I say. If you used a single thread pool executor, there is no risk at all of a second task starting execution _at all_ if the previous operation is not finished.

Comment: No. Operation's execution is not limited to the execution of the thread that starts it. The thread starts the operation, then the thread complete the execution, but the operation is still executing in background. So even with a single thread, even if the operation is not completed, there can be a second execution which starts a second operation, concurrent to the first. Moreover, TimerTask implementation is single-threaded too.